# Compare a list of lists with another list, and return common one

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Let´s say I have the following list of lists:

```
list1 = [[A,B],[C,D],[E, F]]
list2 = [A, B, F]
```

I want a function to return the common list with respect to the first one. The expecting result of this example would be:

```
result = [[A,B],[],[F]]
```

I already tried to iterate over each element of list1, and by comparing with list2, create a new array appending each element. I know how to iterate over the list of lists, but I do not find the way to create a list of lists for "result".

The lists aren't large, about 5 elements. There is a possibility that the items can be repeated, but the order within the lists, inside the whole list, is not important.

Comment: In your real data, how big are these lists, particularly `list2`? If `list2` is large it will be faster if you make a set from it.

Comment: Also, can `list2` or the sublists of `list1` contain repeated items? Do you need to preserve the original order in the new sublists?

Comment: Even if non functional, show your code

Comment: @PM2Ring They aren't large, about 5 elements. And yes, is a possibility that the items can be repeated, but the order within the lists, inside the whole list, is not important. Thank you!

Comment: @ealvaradop Thanks for that info! But you should put it in the question itself, don't bury it down here in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one approach. Using `list comprehension`

**Ex:**

```
list1 = [["A","B"],["C","D"],["E", "F"]]
list2 = ["A", "B", "F"]

result = [[j for j in i if j in list2] for i in list1]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['A', 'B'], [], ['F']]
```

Comment: I've never learned about this feature in python, I'll have to look into it. Thanks @Rakesh

Comment: @vividpk21 If you never learned about list comprehensions in Python then you had a very bad teacher.

Comment: The solution worked fine @Rakesh. I knew about `list comprehension` but this idea didn`t come to my mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

With set arithmetic, extremely easy and fast:

```
set2 = set(list2)
[list(set(e) & set2) for e in list1]
```

If the lists can contain non-unique items, then... let's use counters!

```
from collections import Counter
counter2 = Counter(list2)
[list((Counter(e) & counter2).elements()) for e in list1]
```

Comment: However, does not work if `list2` contains a certain value multiple times.

Comment: @Thomas what should be in you case?

Comment: @Thomas: That is fair. Then again, OP had no data to represent such a scenario.

Comment: @Amadan That is true, just taking the eventualities into account… :-)

Comment: FWIW, `set2.intersection(e)` is slightly faster, although longer to type. ;) And of course neither variation preserves order, which the OP _might_ need to do.

Comment: @Thomas Yes. The problem, as @BearBrown says, is that output is not quite defined in that scenario, and would need additional clarification from OP. For example, what should be the output for `list1=[[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]]` and `list2=[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`? Presumably `[[1, 1, 2, 2]]` - yet none of the current solutions produces it - so it's not really fair to only complain on mine :D But very well, challenge accepted!

Comment: @PM2Ring: Then my second solution probably stands to be the correct one (no to order-preserving, yes to duplicate handling)

Answer (score 4):

Use `set` and `intersection`

```
In [18]: [list(set(item).intersection(list2)) for item in list1]
Out[18]: [['A', 'B'], [], ['F']]
```

Iterate through the list of list and find the intersection with the base list.

Or , Use `list comprehension`,

```
In [16]: [[i for i in item if i in list2]for item in list1]
Out[16]: [['A', 'B'], [], ['F']]
```

Comment: @Thomas, You can see the timings, We posted almost at same time. So, Updated with another solution.

Comment: Please point out the similarities between your solution proposals and the other ones. Thanks. Removed the downvote so far.

Comment: @Thomas Answerers aren't obliged to compare their answer to the others. But it is nice if they add some explanation to the code...

Answer (score 0):

Using basic python,

```
list1=[[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]]
list2=[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

result = []
for sublist in list1:
    filtered = []
    for item in sublist:
        if item in list2:
            filtered.append(item)
    result.append(filtered)

print(result)
```

gives

```
[[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]]

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
listA = [['A','B'],['C','D'],['E', 'F']]
listB = ['A', 'B', 'F']
listOut = []
for item in listA:
    temp = []
    for inner in item:
        for b in listB:
            if inner == b:
                temp.append(b)
    listOut.append(temp)


print(listOut)
```

This does what you've asked.

Comment: ```[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]

[Program finished] ``` which is incorrect for ```list1=[[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]]
list2=[1, 1, 2, 2, 2]```